# IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed - Open ID Connect Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are implementing authentication in asp.net mvc application using open id connect.

```
        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretkey)),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = authority,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                   // ValidAudience = strAudience
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // when an auth code is received...
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => {
                        // get the OpenID Connect code passed from Azure AD on successful auth
                        string code = context.Code;

                        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                        var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(code);

                        //// successful auth
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                    {
                        // We can remove claims that are not necessary in this context, mitigating the cookie size.
                        var identity = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                        return Task.FromResult(0); 

                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) => {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }

            });
```

Authentication is successful, and I am able to get the code.

I am using Authorize attribute  in my controller.

Using msal, we received auth token and id_token. I am getting the proper tokens, still after getting tokens, I am getting Infinite loop. I am used UseKentorOwinCookieSaver also. But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization code is not a JWT.
You use it to get JWTs from Azure AD's token endpoint.

You can use MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) for this, or make the call yourself. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: Thank You, I impemented msal to get auth token and id_token. I am getting the proper tokens, still after getting tokens, I am getting Infinite loop. I am used UseKentorOwinCookieSaver also. But nothing is working.